# Django Publishable is_public field

Tags: python, django

So at work we are using django-publish for publishing case studies. Whenever a case study is published, it is viewable by a regular user. However if it is in draft mode, and user is logged in as an admin, on the index page he should be able to see all the case studies, whether published or still in draft mode, that would link to the actual case study pages for each, however for studies in draft mode '?draft' should be appended to the individual url. Hopefully that makes sense.

My problem is that 'is_public' field, inherited from the Publishable class, shows up correctly when viewed by the regular user, however when admin is logged in and is trying to view the page, is_public field always shows up as False, even though it is clearly True in the database.

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.slug:
        if self.is_public:
            return reverse('case-study', args=(self.slug,))
        else:
            return reverse('case-study', args=(self.slug,)) + '?draft'
    return reverse('work',)
```

I have this from the model get_absolute_url method, thus when logged in as admin, every case study has '?draft' appended to it.

I would appreciate any help with this.

This is the full model:

```
class CaseStudy(Publishable, Sortable):
# Text
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
subtitle = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
description = models.CharField('Summary', max_length=255)
challenge = models.TextField('The Challenge')
solution = models.TextField('Our Solution')

# Images
image = models.ImageField('Thumbnail', upload_to="case-study/thumbs")
header = models.ImageField('Header Image', upload_to="case-study/header")

# Client Meta
client = models.ForeignKey(Client, null=True, blank=True)
expertise = models.ManyToManyField(Expertise)
capability = models.ManyToManyField(Capabilty)
services = models.TextField(blank=True, help_text='One per line')

# Formatting
scheme = models.CharField('Color Palette', max_length=100, choices=COLOR_SCHEMES)

# Display Options
home_page = models.BooleanField('Feature on Home Page?', default=False)
work_page = models.BooleanField('Feature on Work Page?', default=False)    

# Meta
slug = models.SlugField()
created = CreationDateTimeField()
modified = ModificationDateTimeField()

class Meta(Publishable.Meta, Sortable.Meta):
    verbose_name = 'Case Study/Story'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Case Studies'

class PublishMeta(Publishable.PublishMeta):
    publish_reverse_fields = ['sections', 'related_projects']

def __unicode__(self):
    return u'%s' % self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    if self.slug:
        if self.is_public:
            return reverse('case-study', args=(self.slug,))
        else:
            return reverse('case-study', args=(self.slug,)) + '?draft'
    return reverse('work',)
```

Comment: Can you show your model?

Comment: Added the full model.